# Random string are added at the end of amp url

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, amp-html

I am using WordPress [Accelerated mobile pages](https://wordpress.org/plugins/accelerated-mobile-pages/) plugin to enable amp for the site.

The amp functionality was working fine, but recently for around 10k pages, the random text was added after the /amp.

The actual URL
https://example.com/gallery/amp

In google 10k URL are indexed as 
https://exmaple.com/galley/amp/energy-review/provider/--/--/--/--/--

Many random texts are added after the /amp.

Accessing the seconds does not return 404, instead it the content of the actual URL(first URL)

Could anyone explain why this is happening and is there is any solution remove the unwanted amp pages.

Thanks

Comment: Do you happen to have the **AddThis** plugin installed?

Comment: @Jamie_D no we are not using the plugin

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43463046/edit) the question to be on-topic: include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that duplicates the problem. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)